# OpenLiberty custom feature dataSource

Tags: java, osgi, websphere-liberty, osgi-bundle, open-liberty

I'd like my custom OSGi Liberty feature to inject/lookup JNDI datasource, the one that is already defined 'as usual'. Something like this:

```
<server description="my-server">

<!-- I prefer this, not being forced to define url, driver, username and password here as well -->
<myJdbcRegistry dataSourceJndiName="jdbc/myDataSource" />

<!-- This dataSource exists anyway, i do not want to repeat all attributes that are inside properties.oracle -->
<dataSource id="my-dataSource" connectionManagerRef="connection-manager" jndiName="jdbc/myDataSource" transactional="true" type="javax.sql.DataSource"> 
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="oracle-ojdbc8-library"/> 
    <properties.oracle URL="${my.db.url}" driverType="thin" password="{xor}${my.db.password}" user="${my.db.user}"/> 
</dataSource>

<library id="oracle-ojdbc8-library"> 
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/jdbc" includes="ojdbc8-19.7.0.0.jar"/> 
</library>
```

Is this even possible to do? I tried several approaches without results (different InitialContext lookups, OSGi BundleContext#createFilter, BundleContext#getServiceReferences).

Comment: If your feature is trying to perform a lookup by JNDI name of the DataSource prior to application server start using OSGi I do not think this will work as you cannot guarantee that the JNDI and JDBC features have been fully started.  Internally, Liberty does this by using a ResourceFactory https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/integration/dev/com.ibm.ws.resource/src/com/ibm/wsspi/resource/ResourceFactory.java but I don't know exactly how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but there is some complexity to it. The `dataSource` element isn't actually a DataSource. It's a [ResourceFactory](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.liberty.doc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.spi.containerServices_4.0-javadoc/com/ibm/wsspi/resource/ResourceFactory.htm) for creating a data source based on a resource reference. In Liberty, configuration usually references other configuration by its `id`, so more typical configuration that follows conventions of other config elements would look like this:

```
<myJdbcRegistry dataSourceRef="my-dataSource"/>
```

Here's an example from Liberty code itself where another configuration element requires a dataSource and references it by id,

[Metatype:](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/d53070ee25359018ad7056b33f97562741e3452e/dev/com.ibm.ws.persistence/resources/OSGI-INF/metatype/metatype.xml#L33)

```
  <AD id="dataSourceRef"                     type="String"  default="DefaultDataSource" ibm:type="pid" ibm:reference="com.ibm.ws.jdbc.dataSource" name="%dataSource" description="%dataSoure.desc"/>
  <AD id="DataSourceFactory.target"          type="String"  default="(service.pid=${dataSourceRef})" ibm:final="true" name="internal" description="internal use only"/>
```

[OSGI bind method:](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/d53070ee25359018ad7056b33f97562741e3452e/dev/com.ibm.ws.persistence/src/com/ibm/wsspi/persistence/internal/DatabaseStoreImpl.java#L877-L880)

```
    @Reference(target = "(id=unbound)")
    protected void setDataSourceFactory(ResourceFactory svc) {
```

[Usage:](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/d53070ee25359018ad7056b33f97562741e3452e/dev/com.ibm.ws.persistence/src/com/ibm/wsspi/persistence/internal/DatabaseStoreImpl.java#L232-L249)

```
        ResourceConfig resourceInfo = resourceConfigFactory.createResourceConfig(DataSource.class.getName());
        resourceInfo.setSharingScope(ResourceConfig.SHARING_SCOPE_SHAREABLE);
        resourceInfo.setIsolationLevel(isolationLevel);
        resourceInfo.setResAuthType(ResourceConfig.AUTH_CONTAINER);
        ...
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) dataSourceFactory.createResource(resourceInfo);
```